# Automorphisims of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

How can I show that Aut($\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}])= \lbrace 1,\sigma\rbrace$ where $\sigma(x+y\sqrt{d}) :=x-y\sqrt{d} $ where $\sqrt{d}=i$.

I know a automorphisim is a isomorphisim whose domain and codomain are the same. But I really don't know where to start a little guidance needed

Comment: The field $F$ is abstractly isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)$, so the automorphisms are all possible things which choose distinct generators for the extension, in this case since there are only $2$ roots, so the identity and the non-trivial one which switches $\sqrt{d}$ and $-\sqrt{d}$.

Comment: This minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{d}$ has two roots. Any automorphism is characterized by the permutation it induces on the roots, and so with two roots, any automorphism either fixes both or interchanges them.

Comment: @ Adam Hughes $\mathbb{Q[x]}/(x^2+1)$ is the polynomial group over the $x^2+1$ group (quotient group) right? Also what is $F$ represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an amplification of comments from Adam Hughes and Travis.

First, every element of $\def\qi{{\Bbb Q}[i]}\qi$ has the form $x+yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb Q$.  By definition, an automorphism fixes $\Bbb Q$ and preserves addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.  So
$$\sigma(x+yi)=\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)\sigma(i)=x+y\sigma(i)\ .$$
Therefore, the automorphism $\sigma$ is uniquely determined by the value $\sigma(i)$.

Using the same ideas, we have
$$\sigma(i)^2=\sigma(i^2)=\sigma(-1)=-1\ ,$$
and therefore there are two possible values of $\sigma(i)$:

- if $\sigma(i)=i$ then $\sigma(x+yi)=x+yi$ for all $x,y$, so $\sigma$ is the identity;
- if $\sigma(i)=-i$ then $\sigma(x+yi)=x-yi$ for all $x,y$, so $\sigma$ is the other automorphism you mentioned (and of course it is in fact complex conjugation).

Comment: why must it be 1 or $\sigma$? why cant it be $-1$ or $-2$? We are still back in the set if we apply those operations

Comment: why must the automorphisms be the set $1$ or $\sigma$?

Comment: Well for a start an automorphism can't be $-1$ or $-2$ as these are numbers and an automorphism is a function.  Not sure I am understanding your question.

Comment: ahh yes but let us define some function $\alpha$ per say that just simply sends $x+yi$ to $-x-yi$ we are still in the set. Why cant $\alpha$ be a automorphisim?

Comment: An automorphism (in the case of your question) must fix $\Bbb Q$, that is, $\sigma(x)=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb Q$.  Your $\alpha$ cannot be an automorphism since, for example, $\alpha(3)=-3\ne3$.

Comment: From what I understand, isn't a automorphism a isomorphism whos codomain is the same as the domain? I mean not all isomorphism have to map $\alpha(x) to x$ as long as there is some bijection between the domain and codomain it is indeed a isomorphism. So why must the automorphism fix $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about automorphisms of a field extension?  If $K,L$ are fields with $K\supseteq L$, an automorphism of $K/L$ is an isomorphism $\sigma:K\to K$ such that $\sigma(x)=x$ for all $x\in L$.

Comment: Alternatively, when $L=\Bbb Q$ we have $\sigma(1)=1$, and by isomorphism properties$$\sigma\Bigl(\frac pq\Bigr)=\sigma\Bigl(\frac{1+\cdots+1}{1+\cdots+1}\Bigr)=  \frac{1+\cdots+1}{1+\cdots+1}=\frac pq\ .$$